# como usar un amplificador operacional ad620?

Tags: arduino

estoy utilizando un amplificador ad620, en este proyecto intento amplificar la salida de un puente Wheatstone con una pt100, necesito medir en un rango de temperatura de 0 a 300°C, y la salida del ad620 debe conectarse a un esp8266 en un rango de 0 a 3.3v, mi problema es que no se realmente cuales son los niveles de voltajes que debería poner en el ad620 y que hacer con la referencia

Comment: El PT100 es una resistencia variable según temperatura. https://us.flukecal.com/pt100-calculator